# Browsers don't load page server by IIS Express while developing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, firefox, iis-express

I have a very odd problem with Chrome and FF browsers, when I'm using them while  developing asp.net applications in VS 2013 / 2015, with IIS Express

Precisely, after few debug sessions (edit / run), the browsers no longer load the page (the site). The page keeps trying to load, the spin indicator is keep loading, if I monitor in VS in Output I see the app seems to work (I see regula messages, like

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131087453511178120): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\70993733\b377d6be\App_Web_tzrs4sq3.dll'
```

but the page never loads.
Even if I totally restart the browser and all its instances (from task manager), exit VS, kill IIS Express, nothing gets solved.

If for example this starts to happen in Chrome, and I try to load the same page in FF, it works. But after few more debug sessions (edit / run), FF starts behaving the same.

This happens erratically (sometimes I can debug a full day, tens of session, without problem), and sometime it happens just after 2-3 sessions.

Any other page (form internet) loaded in that browser still works just fine. Somehow it seems the browser cannot get back data from local IIS Express.

The only solution I found so far was to restart PC - after that, the debug session works, but also, till some moment.

I cannot tell if this happens in IE or Edge also, because it never happen to me with them, but I'm using them rarely (because I'm more accustomed with Chrome and FF's web developer tools - source, console, etc).

Did anyone encountered this behavior?
Any solution, or advice?

---

**Correction:**

Only Chrome still fails to load page even after restart and closing all instances in Task Manager.
FF (at least in latest version) seems to recover after a close / kill in Task Manager

Thank you